# Laravel Login from 2 Table with 1 Login Form

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-authentication

**Hi there! can you help me? i have some trouble.**

Anyone know how to do login based on 2 table (table users + table admin) but in 1 login form?

**Table Users**

- id
- name
- email
- password

**Table Admin**

- id
- name
- email
- password

what i syntax should i put here?? (LoginController.php)

```
public function login(Request $request){
    //syntax
}
```

or maybe i must do something again? thanks!!

Comment: Instead of having two separate logins, it's best practice and most common (therefore best for UX purposes) to have roles on accounts. https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

Comment: i can do it if it has roles on table Users, but i need to complete this trouble

Comment: you can try with one table first and in case of failure try to login with the other table, although @PatricNox have suggested the correct way but in case you can't update everything just go by this way